# Extract extension from variable filename with data.table

Tags: string, data.table

I have a data.table storing heterogeneous file names in a string column.
I want to extract the extension from that column, always taking the characters after the last dot occurrence. Sometimes the filename may contain more dots.

I tried:

```
files0=data.table(filename=c("simple_file.csv","file with.two dots.xls"))
files0[,chunks:=length(tstrsplit(filename,"\\."))]
files0[,extension:=tstrsplit(filename,"\\.")[chunks]]
```

How do I make sure that `tstrsplit` is only applied to each row so that this approach works?

PS: I also managed to generate a column with storing the correct number of text "chunks" with `str_count`, but the problem remains that when I want to create the "extension" column, the entire "filename" column seems to be used for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `sapply` or `strsplit`, those will add unnecessary complexity and inefficiency. We can use `tools::file_ext` (built-in to R) or just do a `sub` ourselves.

```r
dat[, tools::file_ext(filename)]
# [1] "csv" "xls"
dat[, sub(".*\\.", "", filename)]
# [1] "csv" "xls"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do by applying `sapply()` function each filename and split filenames using `strsplit()` then extract last element of each split using `tail(1)`

```
files0[, extension := sapply(strsplit(filename, "\\."),tail,1)]
```

also you can use simply:

```
files0[, extension := sub(".*\\.", "", filename)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Rashid ur Rehman, found a simpler way to make it work:

```
files0[, extension := sapply(strsplit(filename, "\\."),tail,1)]
```